# Android: equivelent of IOS' "applicationDidEnterBackground()"

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onpause

I am working on an app and in the IOS version whenever an external event happens such as the home button or a call comes in the app shows its password entry screen as it shows sensitive data.

I am trying to replicate this in android, I am having trouble because the lifecycle methods can be called and it does not necessarily mean that it was an external event like another app taking focus.

Is there a standard way to detect if onPause() was called because a external event triggered it?

Edit: I have a partially working solution:

```
@Override
public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);

    Intent login = new Intent(this, AppEntryPoint.class);
    login.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(login);
}
```

The issue with this is that if the home button is pressed, this method is called but as the app loses focus it is then brought back into focus by the login intent being fired.

The same applies to the open apps button, pressing it my app goes to the login screen which obscures the view of the page but then it has focus again immediately.

I want the intent to fire but for it not to bring the app back into focus.

Comment: You must filter this intent call somehow accoding to your app's logic. The if(level >= TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) condition must be extended somehow.

Comment: I am adding extra conditions I just removed them to make it easy to see the issue, the problem is not with this method. It is with the startActivity() call, the app loses focus for a split second but then is pulled immediately back into the foreground. I need to stop this happening but I am not sure how.

Comment: I need to stop this happening but I am not sure how > show other parts of the apps too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) callback for this.

> Level for onTrimMemory(int): the process had been showing a user
>   interface, and is no longer doing so. Large allocations with the UI
>   should be released at this point to allow memory to be better managed.

Example for it:

Create a class which extends from `Application`, register it in the Manifest and override it's `onTrimMemory`.

manifest:

```
 <application
        android:name=".AppContext" // the declared class name
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="icon"
        >
```

Aplication class:

```
public class AppContext extends Application{

....

@Override
    public void onTrimMemory(int level) {
        super.onTrimMemory(level);

        if(level >= TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN)
        {
          //do your job here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you implemented this and found it reliable? Just reading the docs you referenced it says "This will happen for example when it goes in the background and there is not enough memory to keep as many background processes running as desired." "..and there is not enough memory..", will this always be reliable if there IS enough memory?

Comment: I have made app with this code snippet and it is working as it should. I mean when the app's UI (e.g. all of the activties) gone, this is always called.

Comment: will this always be reliable if there IS enough memory? > Yes

Comment: I have been trying to implement something that works suitably using your example as a basis. If I detect that the screen is hidden in onTrimMemory(), user is not entering their pin (obscures screen) and is currently logged into the app I am able to start a new intent to the password page. The problem is if the home page is pressed the intent fires after this and brings the app back into focus which isn't ideal. How did you get around this?

Comment: It does not totally clear what do you want to achieve exactly. Please give more details/code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't share all of my code, but the basic gist of it is to:

**Set static integers to track the app's state**

For example:

```
private static int resumed = 0;
private static int paused = 0;
private static int started = 0;
private static int stopped = 0;
private static boolean appInBackground = true;
```

**Update these integers accordingly**

For example:

```
@Override
public void on ActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    ++resumed;
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    ++paused;
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    ++stopped;
    if(stopped == started) {
        appInBackground = true;
        // other stuff here
    }
}
```

**User that logic to determine what state the app is in**

For example:

```
public static boolean isApplicationInForeground() {
    return resumed > paused;
}
```

All of this is in a `AppLifecycleHandler` file. I hope this helps, despite my inability to share all the details of my code!